# Is possible to React Native run a socket server?

Tags: node.js, react-native, sockets, websocket, server

I'd like to make a app with React-Native that's accept connections from another devices (Desktops or mobiles) through raw tcp sockets (like node's Net API) or WebSockets (like Socket.io). The point is that, socket server must be running on the React-Native's App.

I already tried Socket.io and react-native-tcp, it works when i make the server run on a nodeJS's application and the client on RN's app, but not the reverse.

When i try to import Socket.io and make it listen on a port, a error is raisen, because RN don't have node's http module. Just Socket.io/clients works.

I think that i'm doing something wrong, but is really possible to do that? and what is the best way?

Obs: I'm really new in RN's world.

Comment: how about integrating pusher? Might your problem get solved using pusher.js.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't create a server although if we create a server we can't connect any other external applications to the server.

So create a server and deploy it in any could service then use it in your react-native app.